# Javascript/ jquery advance redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have two websites (twigplay.com and mimuz.com).  I want to redirect twigplay.com pages to the corresponding mimuz.com pages.  For example, if the user navigates to twigplay.com/about.html, I want them to be redirected to mimuz.com/about.html.  I want this to be dynamic, because I have over 60,000 URLs.  I have an idea on how to do that, but I don't know much about javascript.

My idea:
Get current page uri > save to variable > redirect to mimuz.com/page-uri

Is this possible with javascript?

Comment: Really dude? Alert NSFW next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var pathname = window.location.pathname;
>   window.location="http://mimuz.com"+pathname;

If you use PHP, place this code at the very top of your page before HTML

```
<?php
$url= "http://mimuz.com/".basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); /* Getting the current page */
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

Comment: I would recommend using  header("Location: $url", true, 301); to make sure the correct response header is issued. Use 302 if it's a temporary redirect.

Comment: Also, you can just set window.location.hostname = 'mimuz.com' and browser redirects to the new hostname while keeping the path, querystring and hash.

Comment: oh thanks let me try your java script i am unable to use php i can use only javascript

Answer (score 1):

Load this javascript in the webpage for all  twigplay.com urls :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pathname =$(location).attr('href');
var arr= pathname.split('/');
window.location = "mimuz.com/"+arr[arr.length-1];
});
```

But i strongly recommend that you use Server  side scripting language (eg: php etc) for security reasons as these methods with java script are only hacks and not full proof.

Comment: You don't have to do the array manipulations, you can just change location.hostname and it redirects while keeping the same path, querystring and hash tag.

Comment: Yes that would be the easier way :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but probably not the ideal place to do the redirect. If you added this javascript to all of the pages on twigplay.com it would handle the redirect for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
      // changes the location's hostname, the path remains the same
      // so if you're at http//twigplay.com/whatever/the/url.html it will
      // redirect to http://mimuz.com/whatever/the/url.html
      window.location.hostname = 'mimuz.com';
  })();
</script>
```

It may be more ideal to setup a redirect on your server though to issue HTTP 301 which communicates the fact that you've moved the content to a new domain. If you're using an Apache webserver you would want to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to issue the redirects. A sample set of rules you would put in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^twigplay\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mimuz.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This essentially tells Apache to redirect any url that goes to **twigplay.com** to redirect to the same url but at **mimuz.com** and to issue a HTTP 301 Moved Permanently header which will inform search engines that whatever info they had about the original url should apply to the new one.